# Maven: Create distribution assembly containing site (multi module)

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, multi-module, maven-site-plugin

I'm creating a distribution assembly (with format "dir") for my multi module project using the maven-assembly-plugin. The project looks like this:

```
+ my-project
   +-- my-child-project-1
   +-- my-child-project-2
```

The child projects inherit from `my-project`. `my-project` is an aggregation, i.e. defines the child project in the `<modules>`-section.

The assembly contains artifacts, sources, etc. How do I need to setup my project to include the site?

The `my-project` site's links to child-modules have to work. As far as I know the links won't work before deployment. Therefore, I guess I have to stage-deploy the site first (?). According to the [docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/stage-mojo.html), the staging is only possible after creating the site:

> This goal requires the site to already have been generated using the site goal, such as by calling mvn site.

How can I achieve this?

Is there a way to get everything assembled with one single `mvn package`? How does my assembly-descriptior have to look like?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if this is a good solution, but there were no other answers, so I came up with this:

## 1. Move the assembly build into a separate child module

Important: I don't know if this is necessary, however I don't have the time to check whether it also works, if the assembly is configured in the root project. Otherwise you have to define a dependency in `my-project` to `my-project` itself with different classifier in step 2, and I think this won't work. Feel free to edit this answer, if I'm wrong.

```
+ my-project
   +-- my-child-project-1
   +-- my-child-project-2
   +-- my-project-build
```

## 2. Define dependencies for all modules with classifier `site` in the build project

```
<!-- Yes, also for the parent project. However, not for the build project itself -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <classifier>site</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <classifier>site</version>
</dependency>
...
```

## 3. Define `dependencySets` in the assembly descriptor. Fix broken links by moving sub module site content to respective sub-directories of the main module's site directory.

The idea is to use the site-jar artifacts generated due to the `site`-classifier dependencies and unpack them. The module links are relative, so unpacking the content into sub-directories named by their artifactIds will fix those links.

```
<dependencySets>

    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>site</outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        <useProjectAttachments>true</useProjectAttachments>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <includes>
            <include>*:my-project:jar:site</include>
        </includes>
    </dependencySet>

    <!-- sites of sub modules -->
    <dependencySet>
        <includes>
            <include>*:my-child-project-1:jar:site</include>
            <include>*:my-child-project-2:jar:site</include>
            <include>*:my-project-build:jar:site</include>
        </includes>
        <outputDirectory>site/${artifact.artifactId}</outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        <useProjectAttachments>true</useProjectAttachments>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
    </dependencySet>

    <!-- sites of sub-sub modules (if required) -->
    <dependencySet>
        <includes>
            ...
        </includes>
        <outputDirectory>site/${artifact.parent.artifactId}/${artifact.artifactId}</outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        <useProjectAttachments>true</useProjectAttachments>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
    </dependencySet>

    ...
</dependencySets>
```

## 4. Define the `site:jar` goal in the root project

This goal is by default executed in the `package` phase and generates the "site"-attachments (e.g. `my-parent-1.0.0-site.jar`), which are defined as dependencies in step 2 and unpacked in step 3:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

## 5. Run `mvn package` to generate your assembly

The result is a sub-directory "site" in your assembly containing the complete site with working links.